# A list of (or method to get) a list of every word in every language

Tags: passwords, dictionary

I am looking for a list of words from every language including slang. Does such a grand list exist?

I know my best bet is to get the `/usr/share/dict/words` for every language and fill in the slang later (no slang in dict/words) but I'm not sure how to download these files. Not sure where to get the slang either.

I see the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:All_languages) has a lot of what I need but no slang. Also, I'm not quite ready to script something to go through that site.

[EDIT] Still need this 2019.
Here's one source.
https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

Comment: A password consisting of every word in every language?  That would be absolutely hackproof.  But how will you ever remember it and won't it take forever to key in each time?

Comment: Every language???? You do realize that there is over 200 languages. Would your list also include Cherokee? or Inuit? Good luck with your PhD thesis.

Comment: I would imagine that an easy answer would be to say that you can assume that any combination of letters 2-5 characters long is a word in some language somewhere if you take care of a few phonics rules such as no more than 2 vowels in a row. Probably most 6 and 7 char combinations too. That takes care of the majority of them. You figure out the rest ;)

Comment: This is not possible in languages, like English, that have no authority on what is a “word” and what is not. It would be better if you explained why you want such a thing.

Comment: It is related but an extension of the question. Never saw that post before, it is useful.

Comment: https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

Answer (score 1):

Unsure about other languages, but you should look at the [English Open Word List](http://dreamsteep.com/projects/the-english-open-word-list.html) as a start:

> The EOWL currently contains about 128,985 words. To make EOWL more
>   usable for computer word games all words longer than 10 letters were
>   removed from the UKACD source list, and all proper nouns and words
>   requiring diacritical symbols, hyphens, and apostrophes were removed.
>   This makes it much like the standard ENABLE word list, but EOWL is
>   somewhat smaller (by 44,000 words or so) since it contains no words
>   longer than 10 characters.

Also, look at the [SCOWL (Spell Checker Oriented Word Lists) and Friends](http://wordlist.aspell.net):

> SCOWL (Spell Checker Oriented Word Lists) and Friends is a database of
>   information on English words useful for creating high-quality word
>   lists suitable for use in spell checkers of most dialects of English.
>   The database primary contains information on how common a word is,
>   differences in spelling between the dialects if English, spelling
>   variant information, and (basic) part-of-speech and inflection
>   information.